# Significance of Animoji in the end credits of Young Sheldon S01E03?

Tags: analysis, credits, young-sheldon

In *Young Sheldon S01E03*, in the end credits scenes we see another vanity card:

[image]

But this time it was an Animoji, saying "Believe me".

Is it just a product placement form iPhone X feature or there was more to it? And what does "Believe me" signify here?

Comment: Why should there be a deeper meaning? Why should it be product placement?

Comment: @BCdotWEB why "Believe me" then ?

Comment: Why not...it's a "Vanity Card"...it can mean whatever Lorre wants it to mean. ..or nothing at all.

Comment: @Paulie_D if we think that negatively then 70% of this site's question will be gone.

Comment: So do we analyse **every card** - Take 567 - https://chucklorre.com/index-bbt.php?p=567 ?

Comment: @Paulie_D if you pay even a little attention then you will see most of them are clear trivial informations which are self explanatory but in Young Sheldon this one is the odd one out.